# How to check if a method has been called on a given jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I'm using jasmine to conduct testing.

Basically I want to make sure that a specific method is being executed for a given jQuery selector.

e.g.

```
$('.hidden-tag').show()
```

Currently I have the following:

```
describe("Test", function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    spyOn(window, '$').andCallThrough();

    loadFixtures('my_fixture.html');
  });

  it("should call show method on the jQuery selector '.hidden-tag'", function () {
    expect($).toHaveBeenCalledWith('.hidden-tag');
  });

});
```

The first part works. How do I get it to check that the 'show' method is being called?

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct way to do it... probably a small hack could help you

Comment: like in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GhMRs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use **[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** selector like,

```
alert($('.hidden-tag').is(":visible"));
```

Use `$('.hidden-tag').is(":visible")` in `if condition` like

```
if($('.hidden-tag').is(":visible"))
{
    expect($).toHaveBeenCalledWith('.hidden-tag');
}
```

Comment: That's not what I want unfortunately. It doesn't even necessarily have to be a 'show' method. It could potentially be any method that I want to check against.

Answer (score -1):

Try install Fire Bug in Firefox. In that open Console and you will get if there is any error in calling 'show' method.

Also You can insert alert(message) just before and after the method. If previous alert() is not called, then problem lies somewhere before 'show' and if after alert() is not called, then 'show' got some bug.

Comment: OP asks for a way to validate the call during automated testing, not exploratory testing.